# Azure Service Management - "ForbiddenError: This operation is not allowed for this subscription."

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I was trying to retrieve OS Data from the getVirtualMachineVMImagesOperations using the following way.

```
ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(config);
    System.out.println("OS Type"+computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachineVMImagesOperations().getDetails("WindowsRemoteServer").getOSDiskConfiguration().getOperatingSystem());
```

and I got the error - **"ForbiddenError: This operation is not allowed for this subscription."**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ForbiddenError: This operation is not allowed for this subscription.
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineVMImageOperationsImpl.getDetails(VirtualMachineVMImageOperationsImpl.java:1115)
    at com.microsoft.azure.auth.Program.main(Program.java:63)
```

Looks like it is some kind of permission error. Please share your ideas to overcome this error.

Comment: Can you please check if the subscription is enabled or not?

Comment: @Gaurav - it works fine with other classes and methods. so hoping it is enabled for sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the OperatingSystem from the following. But still it shows **"ForbiddenError: This operation is not allowed for this subscription."** while I'm trying to use VirtualMachineVMImageOperations Class.

```
System.out.println("OS Type"+computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations().get("WindowsRemoteServer", "WindowsRemoteServer", "WindowsRemoteServer").getOSVirtualHardDisk().getOperatingSystem());
```

any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to try with a different subscription?